# Having problems with the & symbol in a url with xsl

Tags: xslt

Trying to use this but it keeps browning out when i get the & symbol

http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=

Any ideas why and how to work around.

Many thanks

andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the & like this:

```
http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&amp;q=data
```

Comment: @Michael Kay Writing the spec certainly makes you the expert. Removed my answer, thanks for pointing out my error. +1'd